# Definition of a primitive polynomial

Tags: polynomials, discrete-mathematics, finite-fields

I understand there are already some questions ([A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358182/primitive-polynomials), [B](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40326/primitive-polynomials-of-finite-fields)) on primitive polynomials.  But none of these clears my confusion.

In page 84 of [Handbook of Applied Cryptography](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/), primitive polynomial has been defined as,

[image]

Now, if I try to understand the definition by dissecting the parts,

1. This is an irreducible polynomial, that means, it cannot be factored into the product of two or more non-trivial polynomials.
2. The polynomial $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}_p[x]$. So, the polynomial belongs to the  polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}_p [x]$, where, $\mathbb{Z}_p [x]$  is the ring formed by the set of all polynomials in the indeterminate $x$ having coefficients from $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Here $\mathbb{Z}_p$, will be the integers modulo $p$,  set of (equivalence classes of) integers
   $\{0, 1, 2, . . . , p − 1\}$.
3. $x$ is a generator of $\mathbb{F}^*_{p^m}$: I am coming to this part regarding $x$ later on. $\mathbb{F}^*_{p^m}$,  is the multiplicative group of $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}$ such that $ \{a \in \mathbb{F}_{p^m} | \gcd(a, p) = 1\}$.
4. $\mathbb{F}_{p^m} = \mathbb{Z}_p[x]/(f(x))$, denotes the set of (equivalence classes of) polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$
   of degree less than $n = \deg f (x)$. Addition and multiplication are performed modulo $f (x)$.

Now, coming back to the point of $x$, I began to realize that I must have some 
serious flaw in my understanding above. So far, I have seen that generators have always been numbers. 
Here the generator is $x$, which is an indeterminate.

Could you please point out the where I have gone off the track?

Perhaps the best way to salvage me will be to simply rewrite my points 1-4. Adding an example will make things perfect.

Comment: Dilip and Andreas have given you useful answers, so I will just add a link to another example. I worked out $\mathbb{F}_8$ in the latter half (ignore the first half, it is irrelevant to this question) of [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/76136/11619). That question gave a link to a table of elements of $\mathbb{F}_{256}$ which is relevant for, e.g. AES, too. The idea is always to reduce powers of $x$ to lower degree terms by subtracting multiples of $f(x)$ from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notation in the book is not one I would have chosen. All the $m$ roots of the irreducible polynomial $f(x) \in \mathbb F[x]$ are generators of the multiplicative group of $\mathbb F_{p^m}$; this group is a cyclic group. In particular, if $\alpha$ is a root of $f(x)$, then $$\mathbb F_{p^m}^{\star} = \{1, \alpha, \alpha^2, \ldots, \alpha^{p^m-2}; \times\,\}.$$ The *other* roots of $f(x)$ are $\alpha^p, \alpha^{p^2},\cdots,\alpha^{p^{m-1}}$ which are also called *conjugates* of $\alpha$.  An alternative representation of $\mathbb F_{p^m}$ is
the collection of polynomials of degree less than $m$ in $\mathbb F_p[x]$. The two representations are connected via the following table:
$$\begin{matrix}1&=&1\\
\alpha&=& & \alpha\\
\alpha^2&= &&&\alpha^2\\
\vdots& \vdots&\ddots\\
\alpha^{m-1}&= &&&&&\alpha^{m-1}\\
\alpha^{m}&= &-f_0&-f_1\alpha&-f_2\alpha^2&\cdots&-f_{m-1}\alpha^{m-1}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots
\end{matrix}$$
where we assume that $f(x)$ is monic, and use the fact that
$$f(\alpha) = 0 = 
f_0 + f_1\alpha + f_2\alpha^2 + \cdots + f_{m-1}\alpha^{m-1} + \alpha^m \tag{1}$$
in writing $\alpha^m$ as a polynomial in $\alpha$ of degree smaller than $m$. To find
the next line in the above table, we use
$$\begin{align}
\alpha^{m+1} &= \alpha^m\cdot\alpha\\ 
&= (-f_0-f_1\alpha-f_2\alpha^2\cdots -f_{m-1}\alpha^{m-1})\alpha\\
&= 0-f_0\alpha -f_1\alpha^2-f_2\alpha^3\cdots - f_{m-2}\alpha^{m-1}-f_{m-1}\alpha^{m}
\end{align}$$
and replace $f_{m-1}\alpha^m$ by $f_{m-1}(-f_0-f_1\alpha-f_2\alpha^2\cdots -f_{m-1}\alpha^{m-1})$ to once again get a polynomial of degree less than $m$ in $\alpha$.
Repeating this process creates the entire table which is often referred to as
a logarithm table but in fact is an antilogarithm table.  For each $i$, the
table gives the
representation of $\alpha^i$ as a polynomial in $\alpha$ -- very convenient for
addition -- while multiplication of two polynomials in $\alpha$ and subsequent
reduction using $(1)$ repeatedly is harder than computing 
$\alpha^i\times\alpha^j = \alpha^{i+j \bmod p^m-1}$, that is, by adding
the logarithms.

Finally, all this works exactly the same way and gives the same results
 if we replace $\alpha$ by $x$
and say that $\mathbb F_{p^m} = \mathbb F_p[x]/f(x)$ etc., but this always
creates confusion amongst beginners.

Answer (score 2):

What is meant is that *the equivalence class of* $x$ in $F = \Bbb{Z}_{p}(x)/(f(x))$ is a generator of the multiplicative group $F^{\star}$.

For instance if $p = 2$ and $f(x) = x^{2} + x + 1$, we have in $F = \Bbb{Z}_{2}(x)/(x^2+x+1)$
$$
x^{0} = 1, x^{1} = x, x^{2} \equiv x + 1, x^{3} = x^{2} x \equiv (x+1) x = x^2 + x \equiv 1,
$$
where congruences are modulo $x^{2} + x + 1$. So (the class of) $x$ is a generator of $F^{\star}$.